# Predicting future calls from past call logs?

Tags: statistics, prediction

I have a lot of call log data. For example

1. John +1789456123 4.29.2013 13:45 34s
2. Jane +1321654987 4.20.2013 10:03 12s
3. Bob +1459623847 4.15.2013 20:12 45s
4. Mark +1379164986 4.10.2013 15:11 33s
   etc...

Can you please direct me to some statistical probability algorithms that could summon this data into something like

'You usually call Jane every Thursday around 10am'

I have no idea how to tackle this problem. Any intro or directions would be much appreciated!

Marko

**EDIT**
For now I have following possibilities and I have no idea which one is really usable for my case

- [Inference engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference_engine)
- [Inductive reasoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_inference)
- [Poisson process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process)
- [Time series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series)

Comment: Hi marko that's a very complicated question with a complicated answer.  The simple answer is that you'd have to look at inference engines. 

Begin with the systems and theory. Have a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference_engine

and

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_inference

Also this is not quite the forum for this.  So I suggest that you move this to a computer science forum.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Thank you for the general directions. How do I move this to the computer science forum? All I saw was setting the question tags.